# Spherical coordinates to Cartesian coordinates with arbitrary origin for spherical coordinate system

Tags: geometry, 3d, spherical-coordinates

I have a global Cartesian coordinate system with a point $A(x,y,z)$ in it. I have a second point $B(r,\theta,\varphi)$ with coordinates in spherical coordinate system with $A$ as the origin of the spherical system. How do I find the global coordinates of point $B$?

Comment: $x = r\cos\theta\sin\phi + A_x\\y = r\sin\theta\sin \phi + A_y\\z = r\cos\phi + A_z$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!
See in my edit the use of MathJax here.

Comment: Although if I were you, I would ask @DougM to make his comment an answer, and then accept this, yet: You did not specify in which direction the axis of your sphere is pointing; you did not specify the radius of the sphere; and you did not specify the direction from the center to the point on the equator with longitude $0$. There are standard answers to the North and Prime Meridian questions, but neither of these would have applied if your sphere was the Earth.